# Wicket 6.22 Automatic redirection to external URL

Tags: wicket-6

I have a wicket (6.22) web application. I need to perform automatic redirection to an external URL. The scenario is described bellow:

1. The customers enter their data in a form
2. The server processes several actions and displays a result page
3. The result page should last 5 seconds and then automatically redirect customers to an external URL.
   The result page contains a "back" link, so the customers may click on it to be redirected to the same external URL.

I did use "renderHead" function to add tag

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com">
```

The issue is that I need to invalidate the session before the redirection. If I do so, the customers are redirected to my ExpiredSession page instead of the external URL.

Is their any clean solution to make it happend?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com">` you can set up an Ajax behavior that will: 1) invalidate the session; 2) redirect to the external page

```
 anyComponent.add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(5)) {
     @Override protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
       getSession().invalidate();
       throw new RedirectToUrlException("https://external.page");
    }
 });
```